# Why Array.indexOf doesn't find identical looking objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, object, indexof

I have array with objects.

Something Like this:

```
var arr = new Array(
  {x:1, y:2},
  {x:3, y:4}
);
```

When I try:

```
arr.indexOf({x:1, y:2});
```

It returns `-1`.

If I have strings or numbers or other type of elements but object, then `indexOf()` works fine.

Does anyone know why and what should I do to search object elements in array?

Of course, I mean the ways except making string hash keys for objects and give it to array...

Comment: And why making hashes is not an option, I wonder?

Comment: Note that by definition, two objects are never equal, even if they have exactly the same property names and values. `objectA === objectB` if and only if *objectA* and *objectB* reference the same object.

Comment: The spec doesn't say so for strings : they're equal if they're both strings and have the same characters.

Comment: I agree with === comparator, but why it doesn't work with == this comparator I dont understand...

Comment: @dystroy—if you use string objects (and the OP is talking about objets), they are never equal because they are Type Object, not String.

Comment: @RobG I don't see your point. Maybe you should look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/ert8G/) is something is not clear for you. You'll see why I was correcting you regarding strings.

Comment: @jbabey Maybe I'm wrong but the questions you link to don't seem to be related to the problem OP has here (check of equality defined by properties equality).

Comment: @dystroy there are string **primitive** values and String **object** instances; it's like the difference between numbers and Number instances. Comparison between String object instances with `===` also are based on object identity and not string value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @dystroy—MDN is not the specification, it's a community wiki. The statement made in the link that the "standard equality operators (== and !=) compare two operands without regard to their type" is wrong, see step 1 of the [the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

Answer (score 48):

> indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

You cannot use `===` to check the equability of an object.

As [@RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects/12604120#comment16989045_12604062) pointed out

> Note that by definition, two objects are never equal, even if they have exactly the same property names and values. `objectA === objectB` if and only if objectA and objectB reference the same object.

You can simply write a custom indexOf function to check the object.

```
function myIndexOf(o) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].x == o.x && arr[i].y == o.y) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zQtML/

Comment: This means, I cant compare whether two objects are identical or not?

Comment: You can use `===` to check equality of objects, just expect it to fail when those two objects are completely different literals.

Comment: @Jibla Write a simple function to iterate over the object and find the match.. Check updated post.

Comment: @Vega - Yes, I know the least option to write custom function, I just didn't want to write custom one.
P.S. Thank you!

Comment: @jbaby—two objects are never equal, regardless of whether you use `==` or `===`. Both the [abstract](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) and [strict](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) equality comparison algorithms (and the relational ones) are defined as returning false if the expressions being compared are objects.

Comment: @vega—that is not a general solution, it is specific to the OP.

Comment: @RobG Is it supposed to be specific to OP? We can do a `for..in` comparision.. but it would be a overhead here.

Comment: Nice method for when jQuery `inArray()` is not available.  I needed this function for sub-object search which took a slight [modification](http://jsfiddle.net/zQtML/10/).

Answer (score 17):

As nobody has mentioned built-in function Array.prototype.findIndex(), I'd like to mention that it does exactly what author needs.

> The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the
>   array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is
>   returned.

```
var array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

function findFirstLargeNumber(element) {
  return element > 13;
}

console.log(array1.findIndex(findFirstLargeNumber));
// expected output: 3
```

In your case it would be:

```
arr.findIndex(function(element) {
 return element.x == 1 && element.y == 2;
});
```

Or using ES6

```
arr.findIndex( element => element.x == 1 && element.y == 2 );
```

More information with the example above: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: best answer and requires writing no new functions!

Answer (score 12):

As noted, two objects are never equal, but references can be equal if they are to the same object, so to make the code do what you want:

```
var a = {x:1, y:2};
var b = {x:3, y:4};
var arr = [a, b];

alert(arr.indexOf(a)); // 0
```

#### Edit

Here's a more general *specialIndexOf* function. Note that it expects the values of the objects to be primitives, otherwise it needs to be more rigorous.

```
function specialIndexOf(arr, value) {
  var a;
  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    a = arr[i];

    if (a === value) return i;

    if (typeof a == 'object') {
      if (compareObj(arr[i], value)) {
        return i;
      }
    } else {
      // deal with other types
    }
  }
  return -1;

  // Extremely simple function, expects the values of all 
  // enumerable properties of both objects to be primitives.
  function compareObj(o1, o2, cease) {
    var p;

    if (typeof o1 == 'object' && typeof o2 == 'object') {

      for (p in o1) {
        if (o1[p] != o2[p]) return false; 
      }

      if (cease !== true) {
        compareObj(o2, o1, true);
      }

      return true;
    }
  }
}

var a = new String('fred');
var b = new String('fred');

var arr = [0,1,a];

alert(specialIndexOf(arr, b)); // 2
```

Comment: yes, but I generate dynamically the object which I search. Thanks.

Comment: Then you will have to iterate over the properties and compare values. You also have to compare both ways, i.e. a to be and b to a.

Comment: Why both ways? I wrote function like this:

    availableMoves.indexOf = function(obj) {
        for(i in this) {
          if (this[i].x == obj.x && this[i].y == obj.y) {
            return parseInt(i);
          }
        }
        return -1;
    }

Comment: That will work if you have exactly those property names. Incidentally, using for..in over an array is not recommended, particularly with the popularity of "monkey patches" for `Array.prototpye` to add ES5 features that add enumerable properties. Use a normal `for` loop with a numeric index, then you can just return `i` and don't need to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 11):

This works without custom code

```
var arr, a, found;
arr = [{x: 1, y: 2}];
a = {x: 1, y: 2};
found = JSON.stringify(arr).indexOf(JSON.stringify(a)) > - 1;
// found === true
```

> Note: this does not give the actual index, it only tells if your object exists in the current data structure

Comment: Congratulations, you are still faster than some libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Those objects aren't equal.

You must implement your own function.

You may do that for example :

```
var index = -1;
arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
   if (this.x==v.x && this.y==v.y) index=i;
}, searched);
```

where `searched` is one of your object (or not).

*(I would implement it with a simple loop but it's prettier with foreach)*

Answer (score 3):

Because two separate objects are not `===` to each other, and `indexOf` uses `===`. (They're also not `==` to each other.)

Example:

```js
var a = {x:1, y:2};
var b = {x:1, y:2};
console.log(a === b);
```

`===` and `==` test for whether their operands refer to the **same object**, not if they refer to *equivalent* objects (objects with the same prototype and properties).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, where you pass a compare function as a parameter :

```
function indexOf(array, val, from, compare) {

  if (!compare) {
    if (from instanceof Function) {
      compare = from;
      from = 0;
    }
    else return array.__origIndexOf(val, from);
  }

  if (!from) from = 0;

  for (var i=from ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    if (compare(array[i], val))
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

// Save original indexOf to keep the original behaviour
Array.prototype.__origIndexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;

// Redefine the Array.indexOf to support a compare function.
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(val, from, compare) {
  return indexOf(this, val, from, compare);
}
```

You can then use it these way:

```
indexOf(arr, {x:1, y:2}, function (a,b) {
 return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
});

arr.indexOf({x:1, y:2}, function (a,b) {
 return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
});

arr.indexOf({x:1, y:2}, 1, function (a,b) {
 return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
});
```

The good thing is this still calls the original indexOf if no compare function is passed.

```
[1,2,3,4].indexOf(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you weren't interested in this type of answer, but it is the simplest to make for others who are interested:

```
var arr = new Array(
    {x:1, y:2},
    {x:3, y:4}
);

arr.map(function(obj) {
    return objStr(obj);
}).indexOf(objStr({x:1, y:2}));

function objStr(obj) {
    return "(" + obj.x + ", " + obj.y + ")"
}
```