# Associative array difference with filter

Tags: javascript

I want to get difference in two array, I wrote this code.
But it doesn't work with associative array.

code

```
function array_diff(older, newer){
    function callback_filter(element, index, array){
        return (this.indexOf(element) === -1);
    }

    return newer.filter(callback_filter, older);
}
```

result

```
array_diff([{a: "A"}, {b: "B"}], [{a: "A"}, {b: "B"}, {c: "C"}]);
>> [{a: "A"}, {b: "B"}, {c: "C"}]
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your objects are not equal according to `indexOf`.

For example:

```
var a1 = {a: "A"};
var a2 = {a: "A"};

a1 == a2; // THIS IS FALSE
```

So you will need to implement your own test for equality. Does this have to work across any possible JS object?

You can convert your objects to strings and compare those, but this does not give good performance:

```
JSON.stringify(a1) === JSON.stringify(a2) // THIS IS TRUE
```

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects) helpful.