# Why does indexOf() return -1 on correct value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, indexof

I have this for loop which adds from separate lists to one called `$scope.stats`

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.totalNames.length; i++) {
    var list = $scope.totalNames[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        var quote = list[j].quote;
        if (typeof localStorage[quote] == "undefined") {
            localStorage[quote] = 0;
        }
        $scope.stats.pushUnique({quote: quote, value: localStorage[quote]});
    }
}
```

This code works. The problem lies below, where indexOf returns -1 although I have checked and `{quote: quote, value: localStorage[quote]}` is the exact same value as the element in the list.

```
//below is stated in a function where the quote var has the same value as quote var above

var index = $scope.stats.indexOf({quote: quote, value: localStorage[quote]}, 0);

alert(index); //returns -1
```

Comment: You are trying to use `indexOf` on an array of objects which doesn't work as you might expect. This is a possible duplicate of [**indexOf method in an object array?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array) and [**Javascript array.indexOf doesn't search objects**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects)

Comment: Great, Thank you these worked!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This custom function solved my issue:

```
    $scope.arrayObjectIndexOf = function(myArray, property, searchTerm){
    for(var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: [Give some credit where it's due](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8668283/453331).

Answer (score 1):

That is because the 2 objects are not the same. You cannot compare 2 objects using an `==` comparison. Take this minified example:

```
[{a:'b'}].indexOf({a:'b'}); // returns -1
```

That is because both of these objects, despite having the exact same contents, have a different object ID attached to them for JavaScript. The objects refer to different objects, so `.indexOf` can't find the object with an id of `x`, in an array that only contains the object with an id of `y`.

You *can* however use `indexOf` when you supply the exact same object as its argument. For example:

```
var obj = {a:'b'};
[obj, 1, 2, 3].indexOf(obj); //returns 0
```

Because then it is looking for the object that has an id of `x`, which is indeed present in that array.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for `indexOf` of an object, `{quote: quote, value: localStorage[quote]}`, it's looking for the reference to that particular object (which was just created in your call to `indexOf`), but what you want is to find the indexOf any object with the `quote: quote` and `value: localStorage[quote]`.

```
var found = $scope.stats.filter(function(stat){ return stat.quote == quote && stat.value == localStorage[quote]; });
var index = -1;
if(found.length > 0)
   index = $scope.stats.indexOf(found[0]);
```

This will get the object reference of the first item that matches quote: quote, and value: localStorage[quote], and then find the index of that item in the array.