# How to compare a LatLng object with another one which is in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. Recently I'm trying to develop associative applications in Google Map. But I bump into a strange problem.

Please refer to the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>

var buf = []; 
var pos1  = new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2); buf.push(pos1); 
var pos2  = new google.maps.LatLng(3, 4); buf.push(pos2); 
var pos3  = new google.maps.LatLng(5, 6); buf.push(pos3); 

//initialize a new object here
var pos4  = new google.maps.LatLng(3, 4);

if ( buf.indexOf(pos4) != -1 ) 
    document.write("yes");
else
    document.write("no");

</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Because value of `pos4` is same to `pos2`, the printed result should be "yes" if the **position does exist** in the array. *However it printed "no" on the screen.*

I 've tried to print out the values from `pos4` and `pos2`. I found that **both are the same** and I have no idea why this check failed. **Is there any solution to solve the problem?**

Comment: Two different objects will fail equality test even if they hold the same data. For example `var a = {test: 1}, b = {test: 1}; alert(a == b);` will result in `false`. You need to test the equality of the [primitive data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) in the object. In your example, this would mean testing for equality in latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Google Maps API V3 docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), all `LatLng` objects have an `equals` method you can use to compare two different `LatLng` objects:

```
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(3, 10),
    p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(3, 10);

console.log(p1.equals(p2)); // logs "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `indexOf` don't work in objects comparison because 2 objects are **never equal** (they are only if the have the same **reference**), [as pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects).

You can create your `indexOf` function, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array). And compare the `lat()` and `lng()`, [function results](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), from objects.

```
buf.indexOf = function indexOf(elem){
  index = -1;
  for(var i = 0, len = buf.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (this[i].lat() === elem.lat() 
        && this[i].lng() === elem.lng() ) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

**Note:** As @greg-burghardt sugested you can replace `this[i].lat() === elem.lat() && this[i].lng() === elem.lng()` with `this[i].equals(elem)`.

**Usage:**

```js
var buf = []; 
buf.indexOf = function indexOf(elem){
  index = -1;
  for(var i = 0, len = buf.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (this[i].lat() === elem.lat() 
        && this[i].lng() === elem.lng() ) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

var pos1  = new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2); buf.push(pos1); 
var pos2  = new google.maps.LatLng(3, 4); buf.push(pos2); 
var pos3  = new google.maps.LatLng(5, 6); buf.push(pos3); 

//initialize a new object here
var pos4  = new google.maps.LatLng(3, 4);
var status = "";
if ( buf.indexOf(pos4) != -1 ) 
  status += 'yes - ' + pos4 + '- index ' +  buf.indexOf(pos4);
else
  status += "no";

var pos5  = new google.maps.LatLng(1, 4);
status += '<br />';
if ( buf.indexOf(pos5) != -1 ) 
  status += 'yes - ' + pos5 + '- index ' +  buf.indexOf(pos4);
else
  status += 'no - ' + pos5;  
  
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = status;
```

```html
<head>
  <script src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="status"></div>
<body>
```