# Push distinct item in Jquery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push only distinct value in jQuery. But it is not working

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf({
            A: a[i].City
        }) == -1)
        arr.push({
            A: a[i].City
        });
    else
        alert("a");
}
```

How do i get only distinct item in array?

Comment: Please define "not working" .

Comment: @j08691 I am not getting distinct value

Comment: This is a javascript question, not a jQuery one

Comment: Where do you define `a`? What does it return?

Comment: @BramVanroy a is list. It has data. Nothing wrong with it

Comment: `indexOf()` isn't going to do the job for you - two objects with the same values are still not the *same* object, so `indexOf()` will always return -1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array?rq=1

Comment: perhaps dublicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects

Answer (score 0):

create one new **array** like key then insert the value of city, next you have to check it the city values is present or not

```
var arr = [];
var key = [];  // make one dummy array 
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (key.indexOf(a[i].City) == -1) {
        arr.push({
            A: a[i].City
        });

        key.push(a[i].City); // push value to key
    } else{
        alert("a");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var arr = [];

a.forEach( function(item) {
    if (!in_array(item, arr)) {
        arr.push(item);
    }
});
```

in_array reference: [JavaScript equivalent of PHP's in_array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array)

It looks if an item is existing and if it's distinct (doesn't exist) it push the item into the array.

Or the jQuery solution mentioned inside the comments: [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array?rq=1)

Which is following:

```
var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(names, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
```

I posted the codes to ensure that someone finding this inside google finds some actual code and not just links that maybe are already down or closed.