# Array.indexOf Not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an angularJS/Typescript application where I am trying to check if an object is already in a current list of objects

```
     if (this.selectedFormatData.indexOf(item) === -1) {
            //doesn't exist so add
            this.selectedFormatData.push(item);
        } else {
            this.selectedFormatData.splice(this.selectedFormatData.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
```

I have used this code before and it worked but isn't in this instance. Console output suggests it should work?

Any ideas?

[image: Console display for objects]

Update: yeah correct looks like a duplicate sorry. I had a previous bit of code where i thought it worked because it was returning 0 instead of -1. Not sure why it would return 0 though

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly?

Comment: indexOf does not match objects...

Comment: I don't think index of is meant for array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state, `indexOf()` is not meant to compare objects. This has been answered before here: [Why Array.indexOf doesn't find identical looking objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects).

Comment: If it has been answered before, please flag this question as a duplicate instead of answering it again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the reputation to flag yet. Won't do it again.