# How to add object only if it does not exist in list using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an empty array: "testList = []"
I want to have a function that adds objects only if it exists:

```
addIfNotInList({'keya':'a','keyb':'b'}, testList);
addIfNotInList({'keya1':'a5','keyb':'b2'}, testList);
addIfNotInList({'keya':'a','keyb':'b'}, testList);
```

The result of this should be:

```
testList = [{'keya':'a','keyb':'b'},{'keya1':'a5','keyb':'b2'}]
```

Usually if it were not an object, I would just do: `if(testList.indexOf(stringvalue)) {testList.push(stringvalue)}`

Though I've discovered this does not work with objects.

Comment: And you have tried... what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript array.indexOf doesn't search objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects)

Comment: What does `addIfNotInList()` mean?  Does it mean there's no object with all the same keys already in the array?  Or no matching `keya` value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comparator

```
    var testList = [];

    var myComparator = function (obj1, obj2) {
      // check if they are the same
      return obj1.keya === obj2.keya && obj1.keyb === obj2.keyb;  
    };

    var addIfNotInList = function(obj, list, comparator) {
        // you can also declare the comparing function here as default
        comparator = comparator || myComparator;

        // check if already in the list
        var exists = list.some(function(listItem) {
            return comparator(obj, listItem);
        });

        if(!exists) {
            list.push(obj);
        }
    };

    addIfNotInList({'keya':'a','keyb':'b'}, testList);
    addIfNotInList({'keya':'a5','keyb':'b2'}, testList);
    addIfNotInList({'keya':'a','keyb':'b'}, testList);

    console.log(testList);
```

You can also use underscore.js's utility functions for comparison: [isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual)

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
```

You can compare the objects with the above code but there's alittle trick in this.It results in true if both objects are like `{x: 100, y: 1}` and `{x: 100, y: 1}` but shows false if `{x: 100, y: 1}` and `{y: 1, x: 100}`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}) == JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1})` ... false

Comment: Yes I just wrote that it would result in false if you change the order

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this, which loops through the array and checks each item against your argument. Each time it doesn't match `counter` increases, so if `counter` is as large as the array's length at the end, then the object must not match any that is already in there. Hope this helps!

```
var addIfNotInList = function(object, testList){

var counter = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < testList.length, i++){

        if(testList[i]) !== object){

        counter++;

        }

    }

    if(counter === testList.length){

    testList.push(object)

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare object equality by looping all elements in `testList`. if you use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org), it is pretty easy.

```
function addIfNotInList(obj, list) {
    var doesNotExist = _.every(list, function(item) {
        return !_.isEqual(item, obj);
    });
    if (doesNotExist) {
        list.push(obj);
    }
}
```