# Pushing non existent items to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this array:

```
var period = [{"total":852, "date":"2016-03"}, {"total":963, "date":"2016-03"},{"total":789,"date":"2016-02"},{"total":456,"date":"2016-04"},{"total":123,"date":"2016-01"},{"total":723,"date":"2016-01"}];
```

I need to display "total" data grouped by month. Which means I have to sum "total" amount on months that are repeated on the array (2016-03, 2016-01). To find the solution I need to understand why this

```
for ( var i = 0; i < period.length; i++ ){
 if (periodB.indexOf(period[i].date) == -1){
     periodB.push(period[i].date);  
 }
```

Returns this:

```
  ["2016-03", "2016-02", "2016-04", "2016-01"]
```

While this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < period.length; i++ ){
  if (periodB.indexOf(period[i].date) == -1){
  periodB.push({"date": period[i].date, "total": period[i].total});
  }
}
```

Is returning this:

```
  [{date: "2016-03",total: 1704}, {date: "2016-03", total: 1926}, {date:"2016-02", total: 1578},{date: "2016-04",total: 912}, {date: "2016-01",total: 246}, {date: "2016-01", total: 1446 }]
```

On the first case repeated "dates" are not being pushed on to periodB array, but then on the second case they are.

Comment: I think it's because the data is nested in your second example so `periodB.indexOf(period[i].date) == -1` is true because there are technically no duplicates at that level/layer of the array. This: `{"date": period[i].date, "total": period[i].total}` does not equal this `period[i].date` - rather, the first *contains* the second.

Comment: Hi jDo, and what do you think about periodB.indexOf({"date": period[i].date}) == -1  ??
This doesn't work either. I get same result.

Comment: Objects can't be compared in that way. From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects) question: *"Note that by definition, two objects are never equal, even if they have exactly the same property names and values. objectA === objectB if and only if objectA and objectB reference the same object."*

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your task using temporary object and one `forEach` loop

```
var obj = {};

period.forEach(e => {
    var month = e.date.split('-')[1]
    obj[month] = obj[month] + e.total || e.total
});
```

Result will be an object with month as key and total sum as a value

```
{
    '03': 1815, 
    '02': 789,
    '04': 456,
    '01': 846
}
```

Working example:

```js
var period = [{ "total": 852, "date": "2016-03" }, { "total": 963, "date": "2016-03" }, { "total": 789, "date": "2016-02" }, { "total": 456, "date": "2016-04" }, { "total": 123, "date": "2016-01" }, { "total": 723, "date": "2016-01" }];

var obj = {};

period.forEach(e => {
    var month = e.date.split('-')[1]
    obj[month] = obj[month] + e.total || e.total
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 2));
```

Comment: Hi isvforall, it does work as you say. But how do I use this kind of data on Angular?

Comment: @EnriquedelBosque It's too broad question :) For example, you can use angular directives