# Remove element in Typescript Interface List when entry present, always displaying negative index

Tags: javascript, angular, list, typescript

I have an interface:

```
export interface ISchoolsPreview {
    // Shared
    AgeID: string;
    School_name?: string;
}
```

I have a function triggered by a change in a Checkbox:

```
onChange(code: string, name: string, check: boolean): void {
    const tempPreview: ISchoolsPreview = {AgeID: code, School_name: name};

    if (check) {
      this.schoolsPreview.push(tempPreview);

    } else {
      //This is where the error lies
      const index = this.schoolsPreview.indexOf(tempPreview);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.schoolsPreview.splice(index, 1);
      }

    }
}
```

Check is defined by whether the checkbox was checked or uncheched. If checked it adds a new element of ISchoolsPreview to schoolsPreview. This works and when I step through it shows up and displays correctly on my front end.

However when I uncheck a checkbox, the indexOf(tempPreview) always returns -1 even if I am passing the same entry.

How do I correctly remove an element from my Interface List

Comment: I think your question is about indexOf. Because you are trying to compare objects, it's important to understand that javascript's indexOf fn does not use a deep comparison.  Someone else offered a solution on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/why-array-indexof-doesnt-find-identical-looking-objects. Hope that helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Array.indexOf doesn't find identical looking objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/why-array-indexof-doesnt-find-identical-looking-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always find the index of the object based on some property in the object rather than using the whole object itself as follows.

```
const index = this.schoolsPreview.findIndex((obj) => obj['Property'] === code);
```

If you thing you will have duplicate codes in the array, then you might have to generate unique ids for each objects and search based on that Id.

**Note**: I am not sure on this, but passing object to index while return true only if the object references to the same memory. If its a new object you are trying to find, which is in new memory, it might return false. Someone can correct me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by changing:

```
  const index = this.schoolsPreview.indexOf(tempPreview);
```

to:

```
  const index = this.schoolsPreview.findIndex(s => s.AgeID === code);
```