# Redux adds duplicate array item when loaded from state

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hey everyone probably a simple question, basically I have a button when i click it fires an action and passes down the whole object that I concat to array if its not duplicate but strangely what happens because I save data to local-storage and after I load it from there it does not check for duplicate and duplicates the array item. My reducer code below maybe the error is there?

Searched as much as possible.

```
const initialState = {
    favourites: []
};

const favourites = (state = initialState, action) => {
const { payload } = action;
switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_FAVOURITES:
    return {
        ...state,
        favourites:
        state.favourites.indexOf(payload) === -1
            ? state.favourites.concat(payload)
            : state.favourites
    };
    default:
    return state;
}
};
```

Comment: What is `payload`?

Comment: payload is an object that i pass

Comment: Is that object saved to localStorage and the one you don't want duplicated?

Comment: so i add that object to my favourites: [] array which holds all the objects that i clicked and is stored in local storage and loaded from there after

Comment: Alright. I don't know the rest of your code, but perhaps you aren't parsing the object from localStorage? localStorage only saves strings. Saving any object to it will only yield `[object Object]`. What value do you get when receiving the value from ls?

Comment: i store the whole state of redux i get the array of objects back, but it just doesn't match the duplicate after that and adds duplicate objects into array if that makes sense

Comment: not really, sorry. Can you edit your question and add more relevant code / prints of your variables? I need a better picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that state.favourites.indexOf(payload) === -1 is always true. This is because the function Array.prototype.findIndex() [does not find identical objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/why-array-indexof-doesnt-find-identical-looking-objects).

You should use an alternate method of checking to see if the payload object is already in the favourites array. For example, you could try something like this:

```
const favourites = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { payload } = action;
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_FAVOURITES:
            return {
                ...state,
                favourites:
                    JSON.stringify(state.favourites).indexOf(JSON.stringify(payload)) === -1
                        ? state.favourites.concat(payload)
                        : state.favourites
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```